# Is it possible to have local types in F#

Tags: types, scope, f#, functional-programming

By local types I mean a type that is only accessible within a particular function

For example lets say I want to take some data, format it, and serialize it to json.

```
let parse data = // hypothetical scenario
    type Record = { root : string[] }
    let record = { root = data }
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject record
```

It seems since the type isn't needed anywhere else this should work. However I get compile errors when I write this.

Is there a way to get similar functionality in F#?

Comment: Object expressions -  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/object-expressions-%5Bfsharp%5D are similar

Comment: @JohnPalmer Aren't these anonymous though? don't you lose ability for some polymorphic stuff when using this?

Comment: You can use `private` access modifier so that your type could be accessed only from the enclosing module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

F# does not support type declarations within a function scope.

The closest you can get to this is to define a module and keep the type local to a module:

```
module MyLogic = 
    type private LocalType = {root: string []}
    let serialize data =
        let record = {root = data}
        JsonConvert.SerializeObject record
```

If you put your serialization code into a separate module then you can keep your type private to the module using the `private` modifier, which will also keep it local to the serialization functionality - not quite to a single function, but reasonably close.

Aside, I think you also need `DataContract` attribute on the record to make it actually work.